# Data not altered when I update the column to a new value with button click

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So, I have this table with a column named "status_request", When a user filled a form and send it to DB, it will automatically filled with '0', and if admin approved the data (data will show as table with multiple approve buttons) by clicking the approve button, the "status_request" column will be filled with '1'. I can't seem to make it work in my code, it's not throwing any error but the column is not updated.

this is the 'approve' controller (when admin clicked the approve button)

```
public function approve($id){
    $req = DB::table('lr2')->find($id);
    $check = DB::table('lr2')->where('status_request')->first();
    if($check=='0'){
        DB::table('lr2')->update([
            'status_request' => '1'
        ]);
        return view('dashboard',compact('req'));
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Approved');
    }
}
```

routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/dashboard/approve/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@approve')->name('dashboard.approve');
```

views/dashboard.blade.php

```
 <button type="button" class="mr-3 text-sm bg-blue-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-white py-1 px-2 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"><a href={{ url('/dashboard/approve',$m->id) }}>APPROVE</a></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems a little difficult, the IF block attempts to update all the records' statuses which seems a little bit odd.

If you want to update the status_field of a single records, try this:

```
public function approve($id){

    // Get the record.
    $req = DB::table('lr2')->find($id);

    // Assign value 1 to the status_request field.
    $req->status_request = 1;

    // Attempt to update the status.
    if ($req->save()) {

        // Return with a success message.
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Approved');
    }

    // Return with an error message about the failure.
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'A problem occured while updating the status');
}
```